# React - Select very slow for loads of data from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react-select widget for items to be searched with. Currently, i return a list of 15,000 items into the react-select for users to search within. Unfortunately, the react-select becomes extremely slow and lags when user starts to type or scroll through the select.

I tried using localStorage however, the issue still persist

Is this a bug with the react-select widget or there is any advanced way of handling this issue please?

PS: Beginner with react

**Component**

```
 state = {
         productData:[],
         searchable:true
      };

    fetchAll(){
            return this.fetchPost().then(([response,json]) => {
               console.log(response);
               if(response.status === 200)
               {
                  this.setState({
                     itemData: json.data.items
                  })         
               }
            })
         }               
         fetchPost(){
            const URL = 'http://domain/api/';
            return fetch(URL, {method:'GET',headers:new Headers ({
               'Accept': 'application/json',
               'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                  })})
            .then(response => Promise.all([response, response.json()]));
         }



          render(
          let options = this.state.productData.map(function (product)
          {
          return {value: product.name, label: product.name};
          })
              return{ 
                <Select style={select}
                                  value = {this.state.value}
                                  onChange = {this.handleChange}
                                  clearable = {this.state.clearable}
                                  searchable = {this.state.searchable}
                                  labelKey = 'name'
                                  valueKey = 'name'
                                  options={options}
                                />  

    })
```

Comment: I would recommend looking at [react-virtualized](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized) / [react-virtualized-select](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized-select), or pagination. The issue here is the browser rendering so many elements, not the computer handling a big load of data.

Comment: [Antd](https://ant.design/components/list/#components-list-demo-infinite-virtualized-load) have a nice demo on how to use it and an explanation on how it works.

Comment: select box options can be loaded once the user scrolls down once the user reaches the second last option we will initiate the call for loading more options. You can use infinite scroll with intersection observer api

Comment: you can have an idea on this one check this one https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandbox-mrm4s

Answer (score 1):

With react virtualized and pagination you can handle such amount of data in scrolling inside select.

But still how can you perform inline search from that data as after pagination only certain amount of data will be available for search and now search will be performed in that only so what about the data which haven't been loaded yet .

And do you think with so much data your user will like to scroll. This is a very bad experience.

So the preferable way will be using **Async React Select** which allows user to search the data by calling api, i.e no more internal search.

Async select is designed perfectly for such use cases which allows to load data in select using pagination and also allow search outside the data loaded.

Comment: i tried to install react async ` npm install --save react-select/async`, it throws an error  `The authenticity of host 'github.com (140.82.118.3)' can't be established`. Is there anywhere i can get this installed ?

Comment: Just install the newest version of react-select, and then you are up and ready to use async by importing the component using import Async from 'react-select/async';